# Whitespace Before Doctype

Tags: html

I know there a lot of answers for this one but none of them work for me.
I am using Wordpress 4.6.8 and with TwentySixteen theme and not a single plugin active.

I am getting a blank line before Doctype declaration (screenshot).

[image: whitespace on line 1]

Here is what i have tried:

- Clearing extra spaces in functions file.
- Deactivating all plugins
- Checking the wp-config.php file for closing php tag
- checking the header file for extra spaces or line breaks

But none of this seems to remove the whitespace. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: header.php only gets included from the template file (index.php, front-page.php, single.php etc pp), if there is whitespace in there somewhere before `get_header()`, that will show up. Maybe add a header("X-Test: whitespace") in header.php at the beginning. It should complain that output has already been started and tell you where.

Comment: I checked every file for blank space. Even i am using a WP default theme.

Comment: Did you try adding `header("X-Test: whitespace")`?

Comment: Yes. But that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `?>` in the end of all php files in your theme or plugins.
2. Download WP archive and copy it to your working directory with replacing all files. It will replace all core WP files, so if there was a whitespace added - it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have same type issue please can you help me.

I know there a lot of answers for this one but none of them work for me. I am using Wordpress 4.6.8 and with TwentySixteen theme and not a single plugin active.

I am getting a blank line before Doctype declaration (screenshot).

whitespace on line 1

Here is what i have tried:

```
Clearing extra spaces in functions file.
Deactivating all plugins
Checking the wp-config.php file for closing php tag
checking the header file for extra spaces or line breaks
```

But none of this seems to remove the whitespace. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: I followed this https://ihuongdan.vn/fix-loi-error-on-line-2-at-column-6-sitemap-wordpress.
method 2 solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, also in my case it was saying:
"Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."
while I was trying to update a page or post on Gutenberg, the problem was in the function.php file, at the end of the file I had php closing tag. after removing it everything works fine `?>`.